# Some of the users not getting firebase validation mail

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have set up Firebase email/password authentication successfully, but for security reasons I want the user to confirm her/his email.
for some users who gives email id as gmail/yahoo it works flawlessly
but for some who gives there company email address, all users from a particular company are not receiving validation email,
what could be the reason and how can this be avoided...?
Note: from firebase console if I click send reset password link, they get that link.. but emailVerified will still not be marked true...!

Comment: If users from a specific company are not getting the verification email, it seems most likely that those are blocked somewhere between Google's servers and their mailbox. Have them check their spam box and have their sys admins check the filtered email.

Comment: thanks Frank, I also suspect something like this, is there any other way I as an administrator mark these user as verified...?

Comment: You can use the Admin SDK to do so: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user